# Apache Hudi create and append Upsert table (Parquet-format) on Dataproc & Cloud Storage

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataproc, apache-hudi

is Dataproc-noob again.

My main goal is to ingest the tables from on-premise sources, store them as a Parquet-file in a Cloud Storage bucket and create/update tables in BigQuery from this file, following my previous post about Dataproc and Hudi conf, i was able to deploy and ingest from on-premise sources, via Dataproc/PySpark/Hudi, and stored them in Cloud Storage.

Next question is about 'Upsert' conf in 'hudi_options' and how can be append new results in the parquet-file that is cloud storage bucket. It is not clear to me is you can update/change a Parquet-file with Hudi.
I want to avoid delete previous loads and only store one Parquet-file per table.

Upsert code:

```
table_location = "gs://bucket/{}/".format(table_name)

updates = spark.read.format("jdbc") \
.option("url",url) \
.option("user", username) \
.option("password", password) \
.option("driver", "com.sap.db.jdbc.Driver") \
.option("query", query) \
.load()

hudi_options = {
    'hoodie.table.name': table_name,
    'hoodie.datasource.write.storage.type': 'COPY_ON_WRITE',
    'hoodie.datasource.write.recordkey.field': 'a,b,c,d,e',
    'hoodie.datasource.write.table.name': table_name,
    'hoodie.datasource.write.operation': 'upsert',
    'hoodie.datasource.write.precombine.field': 'x',
    'hoodie.upsert.shuffle.parallelism': 2,
    'hoodie.insert.shuffle.parallelism': 2,
    'path': table_location,
    'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.enable': 'true',
    'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.database': database_name,
    'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.table': table_name,
    'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.partition_extractor_class': 'org.apache.hudi.hive.MultiPartKeysValueExtractor',
    'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.use_jdbc': 'false',
    'hoodie.datasource.hive_sync.mode': 'hms'
}


updates.write.format("hudi") \
    .options(**hudi_options) \
    .mode("append") \
    .save()
```

However, generate another Parquet-file in Cloud Storage.

Is there anything i´m missing in configuration?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Apache Hudi and the other open Data Lakehouse formats (Apache Iceberg and Delta) creates data snapshots in order to bring ACID transactions to parquet format. In each commit, they read the existing data in the changed partitions, apply the changes in memory and tmp files (appending new data, deleting or updating existing data), the re-write the whole data to the partitions. Later they delete the old files based on the cleaning policy, and you can use them for time travel queries or for rollback.

> I want to avoid delete previous loads

While your `OPERATION_OPT_KEY` is not `insert_overwrite_table` or `insert_overwrite`, and spark save mode is not `overwrite`, don't worry about the previous loads.

> and only store one Parquet-file per table

If you want to compact the data and have a single big parquet file in your table, you need to increase `hoodie.parquet.max.file.size` which is 120MB by default, because Hudi splits the parquet files which exceeds this size in chunks.